# VS Setup Project Windows service questions

Tags: windows-services, installation, setup-project

1. My setup project installs a windows service. Right now this action is in the Install category. Would the commit category be a better location for it?
2. I've added a custom action to remove the service in the Uninstall category, but when I run the uninstall, the user is prompted to shut down the service. As the user should never really know that the service exists, I'd rather this never pops up, but rather stops the service on its own and simply uninstalls this. I can't seem to find a setting for that. How might I accomplish it?
3. Should I have anything in the rollback section? I added the same custom action for the install/uninstall, figuring it would be smart enough to uninstall the service if the rollback occurs after the service was installed. Is this correct? Would it be moot if I installed on commit instead?